UML and ownership of GeneralizationSet
The UML 2.5.1 specification, available for free download on the OMG website, does not specifically state what the ideal owner Element of a GeneralizationSet should be. We have the following options:

Since GeneralizationSet is a PackageableElement, we can assign ownership to a Package. This would most likely be the nearest enclosing Namespace for all of the Generalizations it contains (or at least for the 'general' Classifier which must be the same for all of the Generalizations in its set), but there is no guidance for this in the UML spec;

Since all Generalizations in a GeneralizationSet must have the same 'general' Classifier, this could be the designated owner of the GeneralizationSet itself;

There can be an associated powertype, but since there might not be any (multiplicity is [0..1]), and GeneralizationSet must have an owner, this won't work;

Something else?


I am inclined to select option 2, but not sure if this has any unforeseen implications?

The general classifier shouldn't not be aware of any generalizationsets. It could be somewhere in a package, blissfully unaware of any generalization(sets). Setting this classifier to be the owner of the generalizationset adds an extra dependency that shouldn't be there.

@GeertBellekens, your comment is a good answer. Why not post it as an answer instead of a comment? Comments are for clarifying the question, not for answering it.

@www.admiraalit.nl because I don't really have a (full) answer, only a comment about why option 2 is maybe not the best option.

To build up on @GeertBellekens's comment, I am not sure there is a universally recommended answer and this is probably the reason why it is not specified on the uml specs. While in most cases the generalization should not know about its specialisations (good oop practice, open-closed principle) there are probably case where it could make sense as part of the design, especially if isCovering is complete (e.g. the reality is only the known specializations and the generalization is only an emerging element used for convenience).

Thanks for the comments, everybody. I am wondering about the lifetime of a GeneralizationSet and model validity issues when the general Classifier is removed ... for example, during model creation. At least the owner of the 'general' Classifier should be notified so that the GeneralizationSets using it can be cleaned up. In general, any Dependency, although usually owned by the client, must be notified when the supplier is deleted?

The lifetime of the Generalizationset is not bound to the general Classifier. Therefore, it doesn't need to be cleaned up, when the general Classifier is removed. Of course, very often you might want to delete it with the Generalizations, but this is not a given.

Option 2 and 3 are not possible, since classes can't own GeneralizationSets. I think option 1 is the way to go.
GeneralizationSets can exist without Generalizations. Therefore, it would be possible to first define a set and later find the Generalizations for it. I can imagine a method that makes use of this.
So, there is really no best place for them. It is up to the modeler. Putting them somewhere near their Generalizations is probably a good idea.

Classes can't own... because it is specified in UML specs that they are not allowed to? Or classes shouldn't own... because in general it's a bad idea although  there may be exceptions to this general principle ?

@Christophe The elements a Classifier can own are defined by the subsets of ownedElement or subsets of it like ownedMember. generalization is a subset of  ownedElement, but there is no such subset for GeneralizationSet. It is a PackagableElement and Components have packagedElement as subset of ownedMember. So, Components  can own GeneralizationSets.

Cristal clear now! Than you for your patient explanation
